# How to install curl on debian 7.1? Getting the following error on apt-get install curl

Tags: curl, rvm, debian

The following packages have unmet dependencies:

curl : Depends: libcurl3 (= 7.26.0-1+wheezy2) but it is not installable

E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.

Comment: `apt-get remove apt-listchanges`
`apt-get install curl`

this will get it done.

Comment: it looks like broken system?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
apt-get remove apt-listchanges 
apt-get install curl
```

this will get it done

Comment: can you explain what the first line does (listchanges) ?

Comment: Yes please explain the reasoning for the first line, apt-listchanges seems useful if not important: https://packages.debian.org/sid/apt-listchanges

Answer (score 0):

Fix/update your `/etc/apt/sources.list` with https://wiki.debian.org/SourcesList